# Visual Studio tracing of WPF Routed Events not working

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-debugging

I decided to try to turn on Visual Studio output for Routed Events in order to figure out why my handler was not being called.  I went to

```
Tools >> Options >> Debugging >> Output Windows >> WPF Trace Settings
```

I changed the "RoutedEvents" setting from "Off" to "Verbose".  (The "All Debug Output" setting under the "General" section was already set to "On")

Then I started debugging again and expected to be inundated with messages in the output window.  Instead I got... nothing.  No additional output whatsoever.  I was clicking buttons left and right.  Nothing.

I tried other levels of output but none of them seem to have any effect on my debug output.

I tried creating a brand new WPF Sample app.  Put a button in there and clicked on it.  No output there either.

Is there some other setting I need to change?  Or does the output go to some other special window or something?

This is Visual Studio 17.8.6 with a WPF app and .NET 8.0.  I am running a Debug build

Comment: Looks like this is nothing new...  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wpf-tracing-using-the-visual-studio-too/50439?ref=native&refTime=1707540937572&refUserId=a9c41b4c-cf91-6740-a134-92a05ea147e3

Comment: [SnoopWpf](https://github.com/snoopwpf/snoopwpf) can

Comment: If you're doing any substantial Wpf development, you are likely to find snoop useful.

Comment: I've used Snoop years ago.  Actually for this very purpose.  It was great but then it stopped working for me as I moved through newer .NET versions.   I evetually stopped using it.   I thought it had been abandoned.  I didn't realize it was still being maintained but a quick search just now showed me it is.  Thanks for the tip

Comment: I should add that I eventually went to Microsoft's DeveloperCommunity and found that this is apparently an old bug.  Like 7 years old.  That report I could find where someone complained about it, they just closed it without fixing.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Wpf-tracing-using-the-visual-studio-too/50439?ref=native&refTime=1707540937572&refUserId=a9c41b4c-cf91-6740-a134-92a05ea147e3

Comment: Hi,@Joe. Could you share your test code with me to try to reproduce the problem?And can you show a screenshot of your output window showing the problem? You can also operate and track in the DeveloperCommunity based on the reply information in the DeveloperCommunity links you sent.

Comment: Hi @HuiLiu-MSFT.  Sorry I did not see your message until now.  My code is about as simple as it gets.  Just create a simple, standard WPF application using the VIsual Studio template.  Put a button on the main window.  Debug the app and click it the button.  This generates routed events.  You will see none in the output window.    Now change the Debug settings for routed events to "Verbose" and do it again.  There will be no difference.  There should be.

Comment: Hi,@Joe. Based on my testing, I reproduced your issue. You could report it in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio) and share its link here.

Comment: @Joe, although the old bug is closed by VS team, I still suggest you to report it again in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio). You may mention there are many users faced with this problem to raise attention.

Comment: Hi, @MiaWu-MSFT.  Thank you I did report the issue.  It has been triaged for about a month now